# How to overcome NOT NULLABLE bean level validation with NULL values

Tags: java, jpa

We are developing a application in EJB and JPA. The basic architecture of the application:

Controller (JSF) (sends data) -> Manager Class (Process it and send data) -> Gateway (do basic rule checking and save to DB).

We are using bean level validation. We have many entities where the primary key will not be available during entering data at the first had during entering form data. The PK values gets generated after certain processing in the manager level. This raises a problem in the controller level; due to NOT NULLABLE bean level validation, controller does not allow user to submit data if the PK field is NULL. But the user don’t have the PK field value during form submission. If we don’t make the field NULLABLE, we cannot submit as controller protect to do so. On the contrary, we allow PK field NULLABLE in the bean level, we will violate a critical business rule.

What can be solution for this kind solution in terms of Bean level management and database table?

Comment: How did you defined entity relationships? Please give us more details about how the entities are related and what do you means by `The PK values gets generated after certain processing in the manager level` ? Is it kind of a work flow? so that a person should regulate the process? Also how do you define the `GenerateValue` of PK? is it done by database engine? for example using sequence or auto_increment? and if so, did you defined it in the entity?
If you can add entities to the post that might help us to better understand your problem

Comment: 1- Yest we have a worklflow for this purpose. there are two kinds of table for single purpose. One is main table, other one is temp table. Initial the data gets saved in the temp table, and once the data get authorized then we insert the values in the main table. For example: to create a contract we have two tables: cstb_contract and cstm_contract; before authorization data gets saved in cstb_contract and after authorization data saved in the cstm_contract. PK generation is done by the database engine. Java Entity class are binded with CSTM_CONTRACT.

Comment: did you define `@GeneratedValue` when you define `@Id` in the entities?